# mysql return empty set on file deletion

Tags: mysql

Below is the file_name I am trying to delete by name. I cannot use id to delete it.

```
uploads\388804_152839054815672_876456439_n.jpg
```

The field name is 'file_name'.
This is the sql I ran directly in phpMyAdmin even after copying the file name from mysql table.

```
DELETE FROM `files` WHERE `file_name`='uploads\388804_152839054815672_876456439_n.jpg'
```

Or in my editor

```
  //  $_POST['f_name'] is 388804_152839054815672_876456439_n.jpg

$path = 'uploads';
    $file_name = $path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $_POST['f_name'];
    $sql = "DELETE FROM `files` WHERE `file_name`='$file_name'";
    $query = $handler->query($sql);
    if($query) {
      // echo "success";
        echo $sql;
    } else {
        echo "failure";
    }
```

Even the Select statement is returning empty set.

```
SELECT * FROM `files` WHERE `file_name`='uploads\388804_152839054815672_876456439_n.jpg'
```

It returns

```
MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0010 seconds.)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put one more forward slash after uploads (`uploads\\388804_152839054815672_876456439_n.jpg`), it is interpreting `\3` as an escape character.